# Conventions for distinguishing the two senses of an ultrafilter on X

Tags: soft-question, terminology, model-theory, filters

Are there any well-established conventions to distinguish the two senses of being an ultrafilter on a set $X$ (when $X$ happens to be equipped with an ordering)?

This ambiguity is confusing at first; I was confused about the "type mismatch" until I happened to see the section of the Wikipedia article mentioning the ambiguity explicitly.

---

Let $\Lambda$ be $2^\mathbb{N}$. Let $\Xi$ be $2^{2^\mathbb{N}}$.

I've been studying ultrafilters recently as part of the construction $\prod^U_{i \in \mathbb{N}} M_i$, which takes a sequence of models, takes their Cartesian product, and then mods out by an equivalence relation $\equiv$ that holds if and only if the set of indices of agreement between $t$ and $s$, $\{i : t_i = s_i\}$, is an element of $U$.

This makes sense, and this would make $U$ an element of $\Xi$.

However, $\mathbb{N}$ itself has an ordering that's very natural, namely $\le_\mathbb{N}$. And ultrafilters can be defined on ordered sets directly.

So that made we wonder whether $U$ was an ultrafilter "on" $\mathbb{N}$ or an ultrafilter "on" $\Lambda$.

The [Wikipedia article on ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Ultrafilter_on_the_power_set_of_a_set) has the answer, quoted below.

> An (ultra)filter on $\wp(X)$ is often just called an (ultra)filter on $X$.

The footnote elaborates.

> If $X$ happens to be partially ordered, particular care is needed to understand from the context whether an (ultra)filter on $\wp(X)$ or an (ultra)filter just on $X$ is meant; both kinds of ultrafilters are quite different.

Off the top of my head, I can think of using *an ultrafilter directly on $X$* as the basic case when $X$ is an ordered set and *an ultrafilter obliquely on $X$* to mean *an ultrafilter directly on $2^X$*.

Wikipedia also has an example in the same footnote of using *of* to mean *directly on* and reserving *on* to mean *obliquely on*. I don't know widespread this convention is.

> Some authors use "(ultra)filter *of* a partial ordered set" vs. "on an arbitrary set"; i.e. they write "ultrafilter on $X$" to abbreviate "ultrafilter of $2^X$".

Comment: The convention that I use is that, in a partially ordered set $P$, a subset that is closed upward and directed downward is a filter **in** $P$.  A filter **on** a set $X$ is a filter in the power-set of $X$ (partially ordered by $\subseteq$).  When I write something intended for readers who might not follow the same convention, I add a comment to clarify what  I mean; it's not safe to assume a generic reader will attach enough importance to little words like "in" and "on".

Comment: I also have the same problem. I use to say ultrafilter **of** $\mathcal B$, if $\mathcal B$ is a Boolean algebra. I say ultrafilter **on** $X$ for ultrafilter of ${\mathcal P} X$. But I am not mother tongue.